# assigning buttons to corresponding images in dynamic situation

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, file

I have a folder containg 1000 or more files. I could show the thumbnails of the files on my browser (using opendir, readdir and is_dir). I also assigned a button to each image. What I need now is that , e.g. the 500th image gets deleted after cliking the 500th button.So no more that image is available in the source folder . 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [delete function](http://php.net/manual/es/function.delete.php) of PHP?

There's a simple example of how to use it:

```
<?php

while(!$file = readdir($pathToImagesFolder)){
  if(file_exists($pathToImagesFolder.$file)){
    delete($pathToImagesFolder.$file);
  }
}

?>
```

Your button should call an action (or a file, `deleteImage.php` for this example) which executes the code just for the desired image. (Usually passed as an argument to the function through the button value attribute)

```
<form action="deleteImage.php" id="doNotMatchForm" method="post">
    <input name="submit" class="button" type="submit" value="nameOfImage500th.jpg">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks alot, but the main problem is that I need it to be more general (using array or sth like that). It is not just about 500th button, I need each image gets deleted after clicking its corresponding button (not just a specific image).

Comment: I know it... but without any code from you, how you want us to tell you more? Post some code.

Comment: In your code, we need to know the name of the image, while our situation is dynamic and we don't know which image should be deleted beforehand. I mean we don't know which button may be clicked and hence which image should be deleted.

Comment: ` $images=array();  
$dir_handler = opendir('test');  
$i=0;    
while($file = readdir($dir_handler))
{            
if(is_dir($file)) 
continue;        
else if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'index.php')
{                    
$images[$i]=$file;
$i++;     
}       
}      
sort($images);
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($images); $i++) 
{              
echo "<a href=".chr(34).$path.$images[$i].chr(34)."><img style='border:1px solid #666666; width:100px;height:100px; margin: 10px;' src='test/".$images[$i]."'/><input type='button' value='nok[]'></a>";

        }        closedir($dir);`